# How to remove slashes inside hashed key in DRF API Key or is there any way to accept slashes in urls.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, hash, api-key

I created an API Endpoint in Django to generate an API Key with DRF API Key Module. The problem occurs sometimes. If the generated key has slashes in it, it can't be fetch by the other API Endpoint. There's no problem if I create it in Django admin side.

I have tried to override the methods in the module so that it can be generated through the serializer. I can't trace the problem.

```py
#models.py

class UserCompanyAPIKeyManager(BaseAPIKeyManager):
    key_generator = KeyGenerator(prefix_length=32, secret_key_length=32)

class UserCompanyAPIKey(AbstractAPIKey):
    objects = UserCompanyAPIKeyManager()

    #some fields

    @classmethod
    def generate_prefix(self) -> str:
        key_generator = UserCompanyAPIKey.objects.key_generator
        try:
            key, prefix, hashed_key = key_generator.generate()
        except ValueError:  # Compatibility with < 1.4
            key, hashed_key = self.key_generator.generate()  # type: ignore
            pk = hashed_key
            prefix, hashed_key = split(hashed_key)
        else:
            pk = concatenate(prefix, hashed_key)

        return pk, prefix, hashed_key
```

```py
#serializers.py

class UserCompanyAPISerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pk, prefix, hashed_key = self.Meta.model.generate_prefix()
        validated_data['prefix'] = prefix
        validated_data['id'] = pk
        validated_data['hashed_key'] = hashed_key
        return super().create(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = UserCompanyAPIKey
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'expiry_date', 'user', 'company']
```

### Working output

```
us5z0Faxg2zEPDo99NmAOgEsf70MpHVb.pbkdf2_sha256$150000$RmkU1OFLKEtW$2YIEK7cZztwVjbqAEoQRLDzxujfTlQ2Fwx4skp2o1nk=
```

### Problem ( with slash )

```
eKi7lj4AvTEgorF7iKiFrzxQZlVD196C.pbkdf2_sha256$150000$ri39ifY6bmDj$DKQHFhTYQOzpEph6v8BUwbdxO/FcLjqDZa/nzq+ujJY=
```

Comment: probably not, why not make the key [url safe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) if you want to pass it through urls?

Comment: That's the term that I wanted to search. Thanks bro!